# Controling event from base class

Tags: c#, .net

I have several DataGridView on several form. When user select rows it will show some data/result, but there is condition. If that condition pass then only result display.

I can check condition on each event of each DataGridView. But I create custom control by inheriting DataGridView. And want to put condition check on base class. If condition passed on base class then it will fire the event of child class, else it will block or not pass the event firing.

I can also write separate event with this condition, but as a learn or fund I want to twit actual event.

Thanks in advance.

```
/*Inherited base Class*/
public partial class MyDataGridView : DataGridView
{
  public bool ShowData = new bool();
  public new event System.EventHandler SelectionChanged;

  public CustomDataGridView()
  {
     InitializeComponent();
  }

  protected override void SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     if(ShowData)
     {
       //Want to raise/pass/trigger event on child class
       if (this.SelectionChanged != null) this.SelectionChanged(sender, e);
     }
     else
     {
       //Do not want to raise/pass/trigger event on child class
     }
  }

}


/*On Win Form*/
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
  public Form1()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  }

  private void MyDataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    MessageBox.Show("My Result........");
  }
}
```

Comment: You have other classes inheriting from `MyDataGridView`?

Comment: MyDataGridView inherited from DataGridView. And I use MyDataGridView instead of DataGridView, because I want SelectionChanged when condition fulfil (DataGridView raise event SelectionChanged when user change selection, but I add some condition, so if user change the selection it will not occur until condition fulfil).